# Rspec test for validity of new object not passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, railstutorial.org

I worked through all of Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial with all the tests passing. Now that I'm going back and making changes to the site to suit my own needs, it's not as cut and dry as "the tests in this section aren't passing." I've created a new "Charity" object that is strongly based on Hartl's "Micropost" object. The only difference is that instead of having "content" the object has a `:name`, `:description` and `:summary`.

This is the code for the test that is failing, (specifically "it { should be_valid }") which is located in `/charity_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

    describe Charity do

      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { @charity = user.charities.build(summary: "Lorem ipsum") }

      subject { @charity }

      it { should respond_to(:name) }
      it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
      it { should respond_to(:summary) }
      it { should respond_to(:description) }
      it { should respond_to(:user) }
      its(:user) { should == user }
      it { should be_valid }
      ...
```

The test actually passes at first, but once I add the validations to the `charity.rb` file, they return;

```
 Failures:
   1) Charity
      Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
         expected valid? to return, true, got false
         ...
```

Here's the `charity.rb`:

```
class Charity < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :summary
  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 40 }
  validates :summary, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  default_scope order: 'charities.created_at DESC'
end
```

I'm sure it's something stupid, but my understanding of everything is so weak I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, my feeling is that it's something wrong with my factory, but I really don't know.

Here's my charity factory located in the `factories.rb`:

```
factory :charity do
    name "Lorem ipsum"
    summary "Lorem ipsum"
    description "Lorem ipsum"
    user
end
```

When I remove the `:name`, `:summary`, and `:description` validations from `charity.rb`, the test passes. For good measure, here's the beginning of my `user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation 
  has_secure_password
  has_many :charities
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your factory to have a proper charity:

```
before { @charity = user.charities.build(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:charity)) }
```

It failed because you validate presence of attributes which were not set like `name`

If you need more background on FactoryGirl, their [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) is really good.